# How can I align multiple Foundation 5 pricing tables plus descriptions?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation 5 with a 10-column grid. Their pricing table is made from an unstyled `ul`, I'm using four of them side by side, separated by columns. The two leftmost columns should contain one set of labels for the pricing tables, vertically aligned.

[image: 5 columns containing pricing tables and descriptive texts]

I'm struggling with how to correctly position the descriptive texts on the left. Placing them in an `ul` as well works for some screen sizes but not for all, because it's unrelated to how the text on the right breaks into lines. (Notice how the *price* container has a different height)

I've also tried to use a table tag (it's tabular data, after all) but wasn't successful to align it with the Foundation grid widths. Any idea how I could achieve proper alignment of the leftmost text elements with the corresponding vertical positions? Any help is appreciated.